# Почему форма не отправляет данные

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, формы

Всплывает окно сохранения пароля, но ни в отладчике фаерфокса, ни в адресной строке ничего не меняется

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>



<div id="wrapper">


<form name="login-form" class="login-form" action="/2" method="GET">

    <div class="header">
        <h1>Авторизация</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="content">
        <input name="username" type="text" class="input username" value="Логин" onfocus="this.value=''" />
        <input name="password" type="password" class="input password" value="Пароль" onfocus="this.value=''" />
    </div>

    <div class="footer">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="ВОЙТИ" class="button" />
        <a class="register" href="">Регистрация</a>
    </div>

</form>
</div>
<div class="gradient"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".username").focus(function() {
        $(".user-icon").css("left","-48px");
    });
    $(".username").blur(function() {
        $(".user-icon").css("left","0px");
    });

    $(".password").focus(function() {
        $(".pass-icon").css("left","-48px");
    });
    $(".password").blur(function() {
        $(".pass-icon").css("left","0px");
    });
});
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qMpeZx

Answer (score 0):

Согласно тому что вы описали, все работает.

UPD: Тоже также и в файрфоксе, все работает.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]